# Why the `/etc/paths` do not work?

Tags: bash, path

I add my php path into the `/etc/paths` file:

```
markleo@mba ~ % cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

# php 
/Applications/phpstudy/Extensions/php/php/bin  # A modificação da versão pode ln-s segundo PHP /, que é um atalho
markleo@mba ~ % php -V
zsh: command not found: php

markleo@mba ~ % /Applications/phpstudy/Extensions/php/php/bin/php --version
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Dec  3 2019 17:26:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

but I cannot use the `% php` directly, even restarted the Terminal.

my macOS version is:`12.6 (21G115)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/paths` is read from within `/etc/profile` by calling `path_helper`:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Based on the [source code of path_helper](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/eb0d59c54eb6fc643e5a4998d46e84067e69eb18/path_helper/path_helper.c) it is rather clear that this command has no understanding of comments in the paths file (something you can verify by just running `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s` or `echo $PATH` to see `# php:/Applications/phpstudy/Extensions/php/php/bin  # A modificação da versão pode ln-s segundo PHP /, que é um atalho` as part of your path).

Remove the comments (and the empty line) from `/etc/paths`, open a new Terminal tab and it should work.

PS: `/etc/paths` gets overwritten when updating macOS. It is recommended to put global additions to PATH into a dedicated file in `/etc/paths.d` to make them available to all users. For path elements only relevant to one user (e.g. `~/.local/bin`) you can also edit the startup file of your shell within `~`.

Comment: Alternatively edit your startup shell files which allow comments and blank lines